# Using LastModifiedTime to sync rows to a data warehouse

Tags: salesforce

I have been tasked with pulling rows from some SF tables to a data warehouse. I see that most (maybe all) tables have a LastModifiedTime column. So my approach was going to be this. As I pull rows from SF into the DW, I would store the most recent LastModifiedTime of the rows pulled and then start at that point for the next pull iteration.

However, I was told that SF implements a lag whereby it's possible that not all rows with the same LastModifiedTime get written to the SF database at the same time.

For example, let's say there are a total of 10 rows that were last modified at 8/15/2018 17:00:00 waiting to be written to the DB. Because of this built-in "lag" SF might write 7 of those rows during a save operation and then write the remaining 3 rows some seconds or minutes later during the next save operation.

So, this LastModifiedTime isn't really the time the row hit the database. It's the time the row was 'cached' to be written to the database and it would physically get added to the DB some seconds or minutes after the LastModifiedTime.

Can anyone confirm this. If this is the case, is there a column in the SF database that can safely be used for sync operations like I've described?

Answer (score 0):

3 Years on you have probably worked out the obvious solution, but I will post it here anyway.

If you know the maximum lag time, you can take that off of your next sync time as some leeway.

If you trust the data in salesforce not to change, and you have a unique ID to reference off of, you could simply re-run the sync, but lie about the synchronization time.

E.g. if you run this sync task every 30 minutes, and know the maximum lag time is about 2 minutes, take 5 minutes off and just skip any rows that already exist or overwrite them. I mean at the end of the day, this restriction is just because of performance right? It's not going to damage your data integrity.

If your rows have automatic sequential ID's you could use the latest ID number instead of a time. As long as the insertion order is guaranteed.

Answer (score -1):

LastModifiedTime is updated synchronously if it's updated via the standard Salesforce UI. If they're updated by a trigger, workflow rule or process builder (workflow & process builders are compiled to triggers, btw), then the updates are asynchronous.

How many objects? Can you create a DateTime field that tracks last data warehouse sync? Your query would then look for records where LastModifiedTime > LastSyncTime.

Comment: SO is not a discussion forum. If you have questions to the OP do not post them as/in an answer, but ask them in the comments section of the question.